# Make sqlcmd work with batch separators

Tags: syntax, batch-processing, sqlcmd

Background information:

I am trying to set up a batch job for syncing stored procedures between different sql servers. I did export all stored procedures into seperate .sql files into my folder. Whenever I want to create a new stored procedure or change it for those multiple servers, I test it on 1 server until I got it the way i want it. After that I export it into my folder. To then deploy it to the other servers, I simply execute a batch - that's it.

---

I've almost figured out my batch the way i want. The only problematic thing is, that sqlcmd seems not to like the standard batch separator 'GO' (`'Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.'`). So i've changed my default batch separator to 'RUN', replaced each 'GO' command with 'RUN' in my .sql files and added `-c RUN` to my `sqlcmd` command.

However it then tells me `'Incorrect syntax near 'RUN'.'`.

For testing purposes I just tried it out with 1 shrinked sql file, looking like this:

```
USE [MyDatabase]
GO
```

Even that did not work. How can I make it work?

Comment: has nobody an answer to that?

Answer (score 0):

Try leaving out `GO` or `RUN` from these scripts. You can change database context without them.

You should be fine to do something like this:

```
USE MyDatabase;
--First query

USE MyOtherDatabase;
--Second query
```